# How to preserve first value of an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array in php. First i added values in it. Then inside a loop i want to add more values in it. How can this be done in PHP?

This is my code:

```html
$household_affected[]=array('Barangay Name', 'No. of affected households');
    for($i=0;$i<mysqli_num_rows ( $result );$i++){
        $row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);

        $household_affected[]= array($row[0],$row[1]);
        echo "" . $row[0]. " - " . $row[1]."<br>";
    }
```

I want to get an array which still contains the first value added to it. But inside the loop it is replaced by the new values and the first value is gone. how can i do this? the output is like this:

```html
Brgy.1, 0
Brgy.2, 0
Brgy.3, 0
```

i want it this way.

```html
Barangay Name, No. of affected households
Brgy.1 0
Brgy.2 0
Brgy.3 0
```

Comment: You can use array_push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output looks like that, cause you do the

```
    echo "" . $row[0]. " - " . $row[1]."<br>";
```

in your loop as well. But that loop doesn't access any earlier elements.

Try this in the end to see what is in `$household_affected`

```
print_r($household_affected);
```

or for an easier to read view in a browser:

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($household_affected,true)."</pre>";
```

if you want to use `$household_affected` later do somethin like this:

```
foreach($household_affected as $household){
  echo "" . $household[0]. " - " . $household[1]."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `print_r($household_affected)` outside the loop. It will print your desire result. No need to change your code just print that array.

Demo : http://codepad.org/xoNdrH9I

Comment: the result showed the output i wanted.. so this means that i got the correct code? there's no problem with my code but rather on the way i printed the output?

Comment: yes just print `$household_affected` outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
array_push($household_affected, $row[0],$row[1]);
```

which will save all the values in the array